# Unable to display HTML elements built through Javascript DOM methods

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to fetch data from an API and display them through front-end HTML elements. The following is my code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>QTrip</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Navigation bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light ps-3">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">QTrip</a>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
        aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex justify-content-end w-100">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./pages/adventures/reservations/"
              >Reservations</a
            >
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Hero image section -->
    <div
      class="hero-image d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center text-white flex-column text-center"
    >
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Welcome to QTrip</h1>
        <p class="hero-subheading">
          Explore the world with fantastic places to venture around
        </p>
        <input class="hero-input" placeholder="Search a City" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Content section -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content text-white">
        <div class="row" id="data"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Footer section -->
    <footer>
      <div class="container">© QTrip 2020</div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap script -->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- Script for plugging in HTML of the Content section -->
    <script type="module">
      import { init } from "./modules/landing_page.js";

      //entry point (executed when DOM is loaded)
      (async function () {
        init();
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
import { resourceLimits } from "worker_threads";
import config from "../conf/index.js";

async function init() {
  //Fetches list of all cities along with their images and description
  let cities = await fetchCities();

  //Updates the DOM with the cities
  cities.forEach((key) => {
    addCityToDOM(key.id, key.city, key.description, key.image);
  });

  console.log(config.backendEndpoint + "cities");
  console.log(cities);
}

//Implementation of fetch call
async function fetchCities() {
  // TODO: MODULE_CITIES
  // 1. Fetch cities using the Backend API and return the data
  try {
    let res = await fetch(config.backendEndpoint + "/cities");
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw Error(res.statusText);
    }
    let data = await res.json();
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    //alert(err);
    return null;
  }
}

//Implementation of DOM manipulation to add cities
function addCityToDOM(id, city, description, image) {
  // TODO: MODULE_CITIES
  // 1. Populate the City details and insert those details into the DOM
  //Fetching the row container with id as data and putting the contents in it
  //column will go inside container having id data
  let column = document.createElement("div");
  column.className = "col-6 col-lg-3 mb-4";
  //explore will go inside column
  let explore = document.createElement("a");
  explore.id = id;
  explore.href = `pages/adventures/?city=${id}`;
  //tile container will go inside explore
  let tile = document.createElement("div");
  tile.className = "tile";
  //image1 will go inside anchor
  let image1 = document.createElement("img");
  image1.src = image;
  image1.className = "img-fluid rounded";
  image1.alt = "City Image";
  //tiletext will go inside card
  let tiletext = document.createElement("div");
  tiletext.className = "tile-text text-center";
  //cityname will go inside tiletext
  let cityname = document.createElement("h5");
  cityname.innerHTML = city;
  //carddescription will go inside tiletext
  let carddescription = document.createElement("p");
  carddescription.innerHTML = description;
  tiletext.append(cityname, carddescription);
  tile.append(image1, tiletext);
  explore.appendChild(tile);
  column.appendChild(explore);
  document.getElementById("data").appendChild(column);
}

export { init, fetchCities, addCityToDOM };
```

**Problem**:

As you can see, I'm trying to build a landing page with cards for each city as depicted in the image below.

[image: Desired webpage]

However, I'm not able to display the city cards through my code (image below).

[image: No city cards displayed]

What is the problem with my code and how can I get to display the city cards on my landing page?

Comment: could you please replicate the problem in a codepen or similar?

Comment: or at least provide us the `../conf/index.js`  and `css/styles.css`

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing your config and .css files.  I had to alter some methods to suit my environment but you should be able to

I changed this code to hardcode some values...

```
async function fetchCities() {
var cities = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "city": "Dallas",
        "description": "Dallas",
        "image": "https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/dallas-skyline-at-twilight-2019-picture-id1175790003?k=20&m=1175790003&s=612x612&w=0&h=d3YJuIgZ1w0D7pgVBqY-rzReI8nbp3_N0z5bENjkE30="
    }
];

console.log("Cities loaded");
return cities;
}
```

And changed the call to init()...

```
<script type="module">init();</script>
```

Try it out:
https://jsfiddle.net/zalidane/58107vLm/1/